# Check StreamWriter->Write() method successful or not

Tags: c++builder

My environment: Windows7 Pro + RadStudio XE4

I am migrating old bcb6 apps to XE4.

In the File Writing, I have to take care of Encoding. So I decided to use TStreamWriter instead of FileCreate() / FileWriter() methods.

In FileCreate() family, I was writing in bcb6

```
res = FileWrite(handle, line.c_str(), len);
if (res == 0) {
    return false;
}
```

I am rewriting above in XE4 using TStreamWriter

```
pwriter->Write(line); // pwriter is TStreamWriter * type
// TODO: how about check success or not?
```

If my understanding is right, TStreamWriter->Writer() method return void.
So, I cannot check the success of `pwriter->Writer()` method, right?

Comment: You can be on the safe side and use `FILE*` instead.

Comment: @barakmanos Can I treat Encoding using FILE*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception is raised if a write fails.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I can use try catch in this case.